# How I create the ball notation with the `tikz-uml` package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I use `tikz-uml` package to create my UML class diagram for my master thesis.

The Problem I have is that the `\umlimpl` and `\umlreal` need an pre defined
`\umlinterface` to work. That is fine if you want to show something like this.

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \umlinterface{Interface}{}{+ method() : String}
    \umlclass[y=-5]{InterfaceImpl}{...}{...}
    \umlVHVimpl{InterfaceImpl}{Interface} 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: impl interface notation]

But the problem I have is that sometimes you don't want to
create an Interface in the UML class diagram 'cause it is from a lib
or something else.

---

### Question:

**How I create the ball notation with the `tikz-uml` package.**

[image: ball interface notation]

See [Interface Realization](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/abstraction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I searched quite a bit and read the [tikz-uml package](https://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/svn/Jap/Jap/trunk/documentation/Guidelines/tikz-uml.sty).

The package has no built-in functionality to create the needed ball notation.

But it is quite simple to use the `tikz` functionality and
create a node with the interface name as label and draw a line from the class border to the node border. The color was found in the `tikz-uml` package code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \umlclass[x=3]{InterfaceImpl}{...}{...}
  \node[circle, scale=0.5, fill= yellow!20, label=Interface, minimum size = .7cm,
          draw, double=black, double distance =0.05pt] (Interface) at (0,0) {};
    \draw (InterfaceImpl.west) -- (Interface.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The code above will create the following diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I added this in tikz-uml. It will be called `\umlsimpleinterface`. The new release of tikz-uml will be available soon

Comment: It's great that you're responding to feedback here. However, I think it'd be better for the format of the site if you wait to post answers until the new features are finished and released. That way you can post examples showing use of the new feature, and everyone will be able to use them immediately. Once you have enough reputation, you can leave comments on posts if you want to notify others that you're working on improvements in a certain area.

Comment: Sorry if I did wrong, I am newbie to stackexchange. When I released tikz-uml 3 years ago, I was not aware of its interest and did not check the web to know if someone wrote somewhere about the package. To fix some bugs I encountered, I discovered solutions here and all other posts about it. So I wanted to warn people that the package still lives and that I was finally aware of people's needs. Actually, the release should be next week, and as you suggest me to do, I will edit my answers to show new features, if it is possible. So thank you for your remarks.